# Arrange letters respecting order of vowels

Tags: combinatorics

ABSTEMIOUSLY In how many ways do the six vowels (AEIOUY) remain in alphabetical order?

---

My approach:

Every vowel can stay in 7 positions out of 12, consonants can stay in any position:

this makes $7*8*9*10*11*12*12*11*10*9*8*7$ this is equal to $(\frac{12!}{6!})^2$ but this result can't be correct because it gives a higher result than $\frac{12!}{2!}$ which is the number of ways to arrange the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose six of the twelve positions for the vowels.  There is only one way to arrange the vowels in the selected spaces since they must appear in alphabetical order.  Choose two of the remaining six positions for the Ss.  Arrange the remaining four distinct consonants in the remaining four positions.

> There are $$\binom{12}{6}\binom{6}{2}4! = \frac{12!}{6!6!} \cdot \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot 4! = \frac{12!}{6!2!}$$ such arrangements.  The factor of $6!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the vowels could be permuted among themselves if we did not have the constraint that they must appear in alphabetical order.  The factor of $2!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the Ss could be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement.

Comment: A more rigorous approach!

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to count positioning ways for every letter indepently.

Consonants: BSTMSL, S repeating

BSTMSL ordering ways: 6!/2!

Let's view all 12 places, there are 12!/(6!·6!) ways to select places for 6 consonants. After placing consonants there are only one way to place vowels in alphabetic order.

So, the answer is 6!/2!·12!/(6!·6!)=12!/(6!·2!)

Comment: To type $\frac{6!}{2!}$, type `$\frac{6!}{2!}$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu Are the $6!*6!$ at the denominator representing 6! consonants * 6! vowels?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note that there are $6!$ different orders of  `A E I O U Y` and every order due to symmetry should give the same number of arrangements of $12$ letters.

So the number of arrangements of $12$ letters for
`A E I O U Y` in this specific order is,

$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{6!} \cdot \frac{12!}{2!}$

Answer (score 1):

- First place the two letters $S$.
- Then place the other $4$ consonants (they are distinct).
- Then place the vowels.

> $$\left(\frac12\times12\times11\right)\times(10\times9\times8\times7)\times1$$